Angular Routing Not Working: Login Form Does Not Navigate to /login Route
I have a login form:
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { AuthService } from "@app/auth/services/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login-form",
  templateUrl: "./login-form.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login-form.component.scss"],
})
export class LoginFormComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {} // Inject AuthService

  @ViewChild("loginForm") public loginForm!: NgForm;
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      const user = {
        email: this.loginForm.value.email,
        password: this.loginForm.value.password,
      };

      this.authService.login(user).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          console.log("Login successful!", response);
          // this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error("Login failed", error);
        },
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Form is invalid");
    }
  }
}

app-routing.module
  import { RouterModule, Routes, RouterOutlet } from "@angular/router";
    import {
      CourseCardComponent,
      CourseFormComponent,
      LoginFormComponent,
      RegistrationFormComponent,
    } from "./shared/components";
    import { CoursesComponent } from "./features/courses/courses.component";
    import { CourseInfoComponent } from "./features/course-info/course-info.component";
    
    // Import guards
    import { AuthorizedGuard } from "./auth/guards/authorized.guard";
    import { NotAuthorizedGuard } from "./auth/guards/not-authorized.guard";
    import { AdminGuard } from "./user/guards/admin.guard";
    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    
    export const routes: Routes = [
      // Protect the login and registration routes with the NotAuthorizedGuard
      {
        path: "",
        component: AppComponent,
        //    canActivate: [NotAuthorizedGuard],
      },
      {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginFormComponent,
        //  canActivate: [NotAuthorizedGuard],
      },
      {
        path: "registration",
        component: RegistrationFormComponent,
        //   canActivate: [NotAuthorizedGuard],
      },
    
      // Protect courses-related routes with the AuthorizedGuard
      { path: "courses", component: CoursesComponent, canLoad: [AuthorizedGuard] },
      {
        path: "courses/add",
        component: CourseFormComponent,
        //    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
      },
      {
        path: "courses/:id",
        component: CourseInfoComponent,
        //  canActivate: [AuthorizedGuard],
      },
      {
        path: "courses/edit/:id",
        component: CourseCardComponent,
        //  canActivate: [AdminGuard],
      },
    
      // Default and wildcard routes
      { path: "", redirectTo: "/courses", pathMatch: "full" }, // Default/fallback route
      { path: "**", redirectTo: "/courses", pathMatch: "full" }, // Wildcard route to handle unknown URLs
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), RouterOutlet],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {}

app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FontAwesomeModule } from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";
import { SharedModule } from "@shared/shared.module";
import { AppComponent } from "@app/app.component";
import { CourseInfoComponent } from "@features/course-info/course-info.component";
import { NotAuthorizedGuard } from "@app/auth/guards/not-authorized.guard";
import { AuthorizedGuard } from "@app/auth/guards/authorized.guard";
import { CoursesStoreService } from "@app/services/courses-store.service";
import { CoursesService } from "@app/services/courses.service";
import { CoursesComponent } from "./features/courses/courses.component";
import { CoursesListComponent } from "./features/courses/courses-list/courses-list.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CourseInfoComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    CoursesListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, SharedModule, FontAwesomeModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    AuthorizedGuard,
    NotAuthorizedGuard,
    CoursesService,
    CoursesStoreService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

and shared-module:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { ModalComponent } from './components/modal/modal.component';
import {
  HeaderComponent,
  ButtonComponent,
  InfoComponent,
  SearchComponent,
  CourseCardComponent,
  LoginFormComponent,
  RegistrationFormComponent,
  CourseFormComponent
} from "./components";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { DurationPipe } from './pipes/duration.pipe';
import { CustomDatePipe } from './pipes/custom-date.pipe';
import { EmailValidatorDirective } from '@shared/directives/email.directive';

const components = [
  HeaderComponent,
  ButtonComponent,
  InfoComponent,
  SearchComponent,
  ModalComponent,
  CourseCardComponent,
  LoginFormComponent,
  RegistrationFormComponent,
  CourseFormComponent,
  DurationPipe,
  CustomDatePipe,
  EmailValidatorDirective
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [components],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  exports: [components]
})
export class SharedModule { }

and the app.component.html is simply:
<app-header>
  <app-button button_text="Login" routerLink="/login"></app-button>
</app-header>

The problem is that routing doesnt work If i want to access 'login' form nothing happens, also, the routerLink doesnt work. If i click it, simply nothings happend and it throws no error?
I tried adding  but it somehow it is there already.
What is wrong with these modules?

Do the other routes such as courses or registration work?

I guess you miss the router outlet in your app.component.html:

